# C# Sorting a list with an integer inside a struct

Tags: c#, list, sorting, struct

Hello ive been sitting with this problem now for a training excersise while trying to learn C#. I'm making a list with 4 variabels and then trying to sort them after one of them, Sold.
Im using a struct to make the list with the variabels and then use a while loop to fill it.
I can get it to write out the list and its all there i just cant get it to sort.
Ive tried using list.sort but i cant get it to accept the command. The struct is as follows.

```
Public struct Sale
{
    public string Name;
    public decimal Personalnumber;
    public string District;
    public int Sold;
}
```

And the list and while loop.

```
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to start");
Console.ReadLine();
Sale[] saleslist = new Sale[8]; //skapar en lista

int i = 0;

while (i < 8)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
    saleslist[i].Name = Console.ReadLine(); //indata namn
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Personalnumber");
    saleslist[i].Personalnumber = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//indata personnummer
    Console.WriteLine("Enter District");
    saleslist[i].District = Console.ReadLine();//indata distrikt
    Console.WriteLine("Enter amount sold");
    saleslist[i].Sold = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //indata antal sålda
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue to next person"); /* tryck enter för att gå vidare*/
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `Enumerable.OrderBy`:

```
salesList = salesList.OrderBy(n => n.Sold).ToArray();
```

You also need to add a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

Alternatively, you could also use `Array.Sort`:

```
Array.Sort(salesList, (a, b) => a.Sold.CompareTo(b.Sold));
```

Comment: Note: He'll have to include the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Thanks alot worked like a charm! couldnt find the System.Linq so used Array.Sort :)

Comment: @Rasse992 If you get your answer, then choose it as answer. So no one will waste his time to read your question again as i did